# How to convert SQL result into percentage

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to find the percentage increase in the last 7 days but I am a little stuck. Currently in the SQL query I have created, you can get the total of the new accounts in the last 7 days. But now, how can I improve to be able to return the result in percentage?

Here is the SQL query done so far.

Thanks

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT account_type)
FROM account
WHERE date_created > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: Percentage of what?  I don't understand your query.  Why are you counting distinct types and saying that is the number of accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table with two columns, say 'old count' and 'new count'. Populate the table with the values you get from your SELECT queries. 
Then, retrieve the values from the temp table to calculate the percentage difference and delete the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below way calculate last 7days count and then calculate before 7days all then calculate percentage

```
    select max(last7days_count) as last7days_count,
max(before7days_count) as before7days_count,
    ((max(before7days_count)*1.00)/max(last7days_count))*100.00 as percentage from 
        (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT account_type) as last7days_count, 0 as before7days_count
        FROM account
        WHERE date_created > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY

        union all

        SELECT 0 as last7days_count COUNT(DISTINCT account_type) as before7days_count
        FROM account
        WHERE date_created < NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
        ) as T
```

Answer (score 0):

With purpose to run all in one query you may consider next query:

```
SELECT
  /* Count for previous period. */
  beforeCount,
  /* Count for current period. */
  afterCount,
  /* Simple math, just calculating percentage. */
  (beforeCount * 100) / afterCount AS percent
FROM (
  SELECT
  /* Select count for previous period. */
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT account_type)
    FROM account
    WHERE date_created BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY AND NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
  ) AS beforeCount,
  /* Select count for current period. */
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT account_type)
    FROM account
    WHERE date_created > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
  ) AS afterCount
) AS tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation might work. Use a `CASE` to only count the new and another to only count the old accounts.

```
SELECT count(DISINCT CASE
                       WHEN date_created > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN
                         account_type
                     END)
       /
       count(DISTINCT CASE
                        WHEN date_created <= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN
                          account_type
                      END)
       * 100 increase
       FROM account;
```

Answer (score 0):

With Temporary table you can do in like :

```
    create temporary table storeCount IF NOT EXISTS (
        oldCount INT(10) not null,
        newCount INT(10) not null
    );

    insert into percentage (oldCount,newCount) 
    values
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT acc1.account_type)FROM account acc1, SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT acc2.account_type)
        FROM account acc2 WHERE acc2.date_created > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY);

    select ((newCount/oldCount)*100) as percentage from storeCount;

    drop temporary table IF EXISTS storeCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one row per account, you don't need `distinct`.  I am guessing you want:

```
SELECT (SUM(date_created >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) * 100/ 
        SUM(date_created > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
       ) as percent_increase
FROM account
```